# Problem on Canvas x, y position (JS) when setting Zoom

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on canvas drawing by mouse event.

I wanted to set body tag zoom size around 80% by using

```
document.body.style.zoom = '80%';
```

But when I used this code:

The positions of X, Y are wrong.

Here's the code.

```
function canvasX(clientX) {

    var bound = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (clientX - bound.left) * (canvas.width / bound.width);

}


function canvasY(clientY) {

    var bound = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (clientY - bound.top) * (canvas.height / bound.height);

}
```

tried to give layerX, layerY as a parameter but worked bad.

Positions are setted more left(-) and top(-).

It would be great if you help me out to apply zoom size on mouse position.

Comment: Interesting use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#container canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let count = 0;

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const pos = getElementRelativeMousePosition(e, canvas);
  ctx.fillStyle = hsl((count++ % 10) / 10, 1, 0.5);
  ctx.fillRect(pos.x - 1, pos.y - 1, 3, 3);
});

[...document.querySelectorAll('button')].forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    document.body.style.zoom = `${elem.textContent}`;
  });
});

function getElementRelativeMousePosition(e, elem) {
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const css = getComputedStyle(document.body);
  
  return {
    x: e.clientX / css.zoom - rect.left,
    y: e.clientY / css.zoom - rect.top,
  };
}

function hsl(h, s, l) {
  return `hsl(${h * 360 | 0},${s * 100 | 0}%,${l * 100 | 0}%)`;
}
```

```css
canvas { 
  display: block;
}
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button">50%</button>
  <button type="button">75%</button>
  <button type="button">100%</button>
  <button type="button">125%</button>
  <button type="button">150%</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

but note that [**zoom is a non-standard property** and is not supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom). It is not supported in Firefox at all.

Comment: Thx for your comment. Seems like this zoom is working on canvas. But I did 80% zoom on <body> style cause I need to minimize entire body elements. So that's why zoom of canvas is changed and I wanna figure out this problem!!

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thx for help!

Comment: After running the code snippet above, set zoom: .75 on the HTML tag, and see how there is a crazy offset between the mouse and the actual shape that gets drawn. That is my current predicament. Any idea how to sort that?

Comment: Don't set zoom    If you're doing non-common CSS stuff like 3D transforms and zoom the problem becomes much harder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654650/how-to-get-a-canvas-relative-mouse-position-of-a-css-3d-transformed-canvas